# Install .Net Framework 3.5 on Windows 10 using Microsoft Instructions

Tags: .net, windows-10

I am trying to install .Net Framework 3.5 on Windows 10 using the Microsoft's instructions.

I downloaded dotnetfx35.exe

And when it runs I get this error:

[image]

So I click on the `Tell me how to solve this problem` link and I get this instruction:

[image]

Could someone please make those instructions a bit more clear?

An iso of what?

How do i mount an iso?

Where am I going to see "Alternate source file path"?

Do I run `gpupdate /force` from a cmd prompt?

Do I need that cmd prompt to be started as administrator?

This is a windows 10 machine and I only have remote access to it.  I can not be physically by the computer.

This question is different than the other questions because:

1. I included a screenshots of the errors I am getting.
2. I am asking how to install using Microsoft's instructions, not just any instructions.
3. I have a specific error number that I encountered.

Comment: This doesn't particularly seem like a StackOverflow question, probably better for one of the other SE sites...

Comment: @dubstylee this was already asked and [answered on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/947660/174557). he only need to do some searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The offline installer doesn't work for Windows 8 and up. You need to enable the Windows feature. Hit the Windows key and type "Turn Windows features on or off". Check off the `.NET Framework 3.5`. This will download the necessary bits and install the framework on your machine. Take a look at the [Install the .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 10, Windows 8.1, and Windows 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/dotnet-35-windows-10) for more details.

If you continue to get the above error, you are missing the side-by-side (SxS) install files. To fix this, you need to create an ISO of the Windows 10 installation media. To do this, read [Create installation media for Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15088/windows-create-installation-media).

Once there, you mount that ISO in Windows 10 by either double clicking it or right clicking on it and selection `Mount`.

Next, you will need enable the group policy setting that allows you to point your the alternate sources for SxS install files to the ISO you just mounted. You will need to read the article [.NET Framework 3.5 installation error: 0x800F0906, 0x800F081F, 0x800F0907](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2734782/net-framework-3-5-installation-error-0x800f0906-0x800f081f-0x800f0907) and follow the directions for Windows 8 (the group policy object is the same for Windows 8, 8.1 and 10).

Now you should be able to turn the Windows feature on without an issue. There are few reasons that cause this issue, but the most common is an issue trying download the files from Windows Update. If you are in an environment that runs WSUS, the administrator my not have approved .NET Framework 3.5 which preventing the download.

Comment: I get exactly the error listed above when I click the "OK' button.  The link you provided has a trouble shooting guide that has the cryptic instructions that i am asking for help with.

Comment: thank you for the edit.  this is much better and clarifies the MS instructions.

Answer (score 1):

A Windows Update group policy can disable the update. If this is the case:

- Go into RegEdit and navigate to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU folder.
- Double-click on UseWUServer and change the value to 0.
- Try to install .NET 3.5 from the Turn Windows Features on and off dialog or through the .NET 3.5 installer (dotnetfx35.exe) provided by Microsoft.

Works for Windows 10 and Windows 11.

Comment: juste remember to reboot your PC after doing the register change otherwise it won't be taken into account

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Microsoft is suggesting you use an ISO of the Windows installation disk to install .NET from it. Which you obviously won't be doing remotely, it probably wouldn't help anyway.

A quick search on Google about it revealed this page:

https://winaero.com/blog/offline-install-of-net-framework-3-5-in-windows-10-using-dism/

Answer (score 0):

Mount the Current installed ISO(Windows-RS1,RS2,RS3,Rs5..etc) Image in the Virtual Disk after that user can run the Command below

**dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /Source:D:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9SMh.png)

Command Execute--
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n2mx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please check Services >> Windows Update Service.
If it is disabled, You won't be able to install .net Framework.

Mine was disabled, So I enabled it first & after that it worked for me.
Try it :)